# GLM with Apache Spark 2.2.0 - Tweedie family default Link value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, tweedie

I am using spark 2.2.0 with python. I tried to figure out what is the default param of Link function Spark accepts in the `GeneralizedLineraModel` in case of Tweedie family.

When I look to documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression

```
class pyspark.ml.regression.GeneralizedLinearRegression(self, labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", predictionCol="prediction", family="gaussian", link=None, fitIntercept=True, maxIter=25, tol=1e-6, regParam=0.0, weightCol=None, solver="irls", linkPredictionCol=None
```

It seems that default value when family='tweedie' should be None but when I tried this (by using similar test as unit test : https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17146/files/fe1d3ae36314e385990f024bca94ab1e416476f2) :

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0)),\
     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0)),\
     (2.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0)),\
     (2.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 1.0)),], ["label", "features"])
glr = GeneralizedLinearRegression(family="tweedie",variancePower=1.42,link=None)
model = glr.fit(df)
transformed = model.transform(df)
```

it raised a `Null pointer Java exception`...

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6739.w. :
>   java.lang.NullPointerException  ...

It works well when I remove explicite link=None in the initilization of the model.

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0)),\
     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0)),\
     (2.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0)),\
     (2.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 1.0)),], ["label", "features"])
glr = GeneralizedLinearRegression(family="tweedie",variancePower=1.42)
model = glr.fit(df)
transformed = model.transform(df)
```

I would like to be able to pass a standard set of params like

```
params={"family":"Onefamily","link":"OnelinkAccordingToFamily",..}
```

and then initialize GLM as:

```
 glr = GeneralizedLinearRegression(family=params["family"],link=params['link]' ....)
```

So it could be more standard and works in any case of family and link.
Just seems that the link value is not ignored in the case when family=Tweedie any idea of what default value I should use? I tried link='' or link='None' but it raises 'invalid link function'.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work finally? I tried the code in the accepted solution and got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with GLR `tweedie` family you'll need to define the power link function specified through the "linkPower" parameter, and you shouldn't set `link` to `None` which was leading to that exception you got.

Here is an example on how to use it :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(1.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0)),
         (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0)),
         (2.0, Vectors.dense(0.0, 0.0)),
         (2.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 1.0)), ], ["label", "features"])

# in this case the default link power applies
glr = GeneralizedLinearRegression(family="tweedie", variancePower=1.6)

model = glr.fit(df) # in this case the default link power applies

model2 = glr.setLinkPower(-1.0).fit(df)
```

**PS :** The default link power in the tweedie family is `1 - variancePower`.

Comment: Ok so it seems I cannot use something like `glr = GeneralizedLinearRegression(family=params["family"],link=params['link]' ....)` but I should remove 'link' item in my dictionary `params`and call it with `GeneralizedLinearRegression(**params)` . Thank you!

Comment: What is the difference between `variancePower` and `linkPower`? The docs are extremely obtuse here. Which one is the `p` in the Tweedie distribution?

Comment: I tried running this code and just get an error `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.toString.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Failed to find a default value for link`

Comment: @EvanZamir the error you have mentioned isn't related necessary to the code I have provided. You have another issue with your pyspark environment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51952535/pyspark-error-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o655-count-when